# In what way were the chess pieces transfigured?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

Inspired by [Childcat15's comment on this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/98929/were-the-flying-keys-charmed-or-transfigured)
 In *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* McGonagall transfigures the chess pieces that the trio battle to gain access to the Philosopher's Stone.
In the *Deathly Hallows* she does a (I'm assuming similar) spell to bring Hogwart's statues to life.

From what we know of the subject, transfiguration is changing the form of something. So in what way were the chess pieces, and statues, transfigured.

(Process of elimination is not a preferable answer, but I understand if that's the only way to get one)

Comment: Superficially I would have pegged "making chess pieces move" as a charm and "giving keys wings" as a transfiguration; maybe JKR just didn't have her terms nailed down yet?

Comment: I've always thought of transfiguration to be related specifically to animate/sentient things in some way: both the chess pieces and the statues are transfigured from a non-sentient state to a sentient state, which the keys are not: they are given the ability to fly and partly interact with the world (at least in the movie), but not to think or act consciously as such.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Transfigure is to change form/shape/appearance. Animation is not necessarily part of that. I assumed that she transfigured a normal size wizard chess set into the life sized one. The animation was already a part of the set.

Comment: @JohnP, a bog standard set of wizards chess pulled out of a cracker and simply enlarged? I must admit I never actually thought of that. Begs the question of how do you give sentience (chess pieces talk in the books (the little ones, not the big ones)) to an object? (I stress sentience, not charming like the keys). If you root out an explanation for that, it would explain the statues at least into plausibility and would be a good answer (not, of course, that said statues are necessarily transfigured. I'm sure McGonagall can do other kinds of magic haha) hmm ive managed to second guess myself.

Comment: Based on the [awesome] film line "I've always wanted to use that spell!" and some things we know about Hogwarts Castle, I assumed the statues in Hallows were a sort of pre-arranged feature waiting to be called upon.

Comment: @thrugog are you honestly telling me if u lived in a castle full of statues AND could do magic, you wouldntn every day be tempted to animate the lot? Haha xD nah but my point is she could always want to use the spell of animating hunks of stone, just as much as it could mean calling on dormant sentient statues. Having said that, I'm willing to assume that the statues ARE a pre-arranged feature (one could argue both ways so I'm happy to say its true for the sake of an answer, I mean, they were built for a reason) so if you wanna work it into an answer :D

Comment: @Mac Cooper Trouble is I'm not sure the same thing applies to the chess set :-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Transfiguration includes the magic of animating inanimate objects

Sadly I don't have the books to draw quotes from, but here is what I have gathered.

I have no idea if the Harry Potter lexicon is seen as a valid source of information, but it lists animating objects as part of Transfiguration.

> Transfiguration is magic which changes one object into another. It is possible to change inanimate objects into animate ones and vice versa. -HP Lexicon http://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/transfiguration.html

Additionally, the HP Lexicon lists the petrification of Mrs. Norris as transfiguration, implying that depriving an animated being of its animation is also transfiguration (again no idea how canon that is).

From Pottermore and the books:

> Professor McGonagall transfigures a life-size chess set as her piece of protection for the Sorcerer's Stone - Pottermore biography on McGonagall learned in "The Chessboard Chamber" instance

While my original thought had been that she transfigured it by making it larger, the text says she transfigured a life-size set, implying it was already big before she transfigured it (although I suspect she did in fact make it bigger). She could have taken a regular chess set and just made it bigger, but she still would have had to change it to make its own decisions, and to not be as chatty as Ron's set was.

Similar instances of animation occur when McGonagall summons the suits of armor to protect Hogwarts during the Battle of Hogwarts, and when Dumbledore animates the statues from the Fountain of Magical Brethren during the battle at the Ministry of Magic. One interesting bit of trivia about Dumbledore:

> McGonagall sent an owl to Hogwarts, asking whether she might be considered for a teaching post. The owl returned within hours, offering her a job in the Transfiguration department under Head of Department, Albus Dumbledore. - Pottermore bio on McGonagall, unlocked content

So Dumbledore was the head of the Transfiguration department, and when in battle one of his first instincts is to animate statues to help him fight. While hardly conclusive proof, it makes sense that someone would rely on their specialties when they're in a rush.

Some have pointed out that the spell to animate the Hogwarts statues, *Piertotum Locomotor* seems to be a variant of the *Locomotor* spell which is a Charm. It could be that animation is in the middle between Transfiguration and Charms, but throughout the books we primarily see Transfiguration experts using these spells.

This ultimately means that McGonagall transfigured the chess set by animating it to play on its own.

Comment: The pottrermore quote doesn't leave much ambiguity. They're lifesize and animate. They were lifesize to start and then she transfigured them. You make a good point with dumbledore too ... Like animating soldiers is transfiguration end game :P (oh, and nice work answering your own question haha)

Comment: @MacCooper lol I said I was curious! and technically it's now your question :P

Answer (score 6):

McGonagall ***Transfigured*** the small wizard chess into a giant size one.

The animation which they do is the way a wizard chess works,

> “Ron also started teaching Harry wizard chess. This was exactly like Muggle chess except that the figures were alive, which made it a lot like directing troops in battle.”
>
> <sub>-*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*-Chapter 12,*The Mirror Of Erised*.</sub>

So there is no need for McGonagall to apply a special charm for the chess set for them to animate.

But the statues and the plinths of armour are brought to life by Transfiguration by McGonagall using *Piertotum Locomator*.

**The mechanism in which both the wizard chess and statues are transfigured is same.**

Comment: @sumelic I learnt that McGonagall changed the size of wizard chess by transfiguration in Pottermore, the rest is from the book for which I've attached necessary phrases. The final sentence is supported from my above sentences. So I can tell that there is no speculation in my answer.

Comment: http://www.pottermore.com/en-us/book1/chapter16/moment2/professor-mcgonagall ,You need to login and must have complete the Wizard Chess scene to view the doc, where it states Professor McGonagall transfigures a life size chess set as her piece of protection to the Philosophers stone.

Comment: *Piertotum Locomotor* is classified as Transfiguration where? To me that was an activation charm that is a clear variation of the *Locomotor* charm spell, which caused pre-charmed (enchanted) objects to do their magic. We have no reason to presume it was a Transfiguration spell because she taught that subject. We should, however, presume that only she, as Headmistress, was able to activate that spell. In summary: the mechanism is *not* the same at all.

Comment: @CreationEdge Sorry if I am wrong but the *Piertotum Locomator* is given as incantation of transfiguration charm. I've learnt that at http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Piertotum_Locomotor

Comment: Yeah, double check that. It calls it a Transfiguration Charm, and each word is linked to the separate types of spells. It's not a good source. But in the books it's pretty easy to tell that Locomotor is a Charm, and it stands to reason Piertotum Locomotor is as well.

Comment: @CreationEdge Double checked it even with http://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/spells/spells_p.html#piertotum ,this source also mentions it as a variation of the Locomotor spell, used to animate statues and armour but not to activate some pre-charmed (enchanted) objects to do their magic.

Comment: @CreationEdge I intended to mention that I suspected that it fell to McGonagall as head or deputy to activate the spell because of her role at the school, but it slipped my mind. I don't know why I feel so sure on this, but I do feel that Piertotum Locomotor is something other than her simultaneously bringing lots of different statues to life from scratch, not to doubt her skills.

Comment: "So there is no need for McGonagall to apply a special charm for the chess set for them to animate." This is at odds with what Hermione observes of the chessmen, "McGonagall transfigured the chessmen to make them alive."

Comment: @AdityaBlaze I was just on Pottermore and it never says in what way McGonagall transfigures the chess set, only that she does. My original speculation had been that the transfiguration was to make it larger, but it may have been the making them alive part that was transfiguration too.

Comment: Engorgio is a charm. Granted there could be other enlargement spells, but it seems that enlarging something (and reducing) is a charm. I wonder if JK still answers questions on twitter haha xD

Comment: @Mac Cooper She does. Just not mine ;-)

Comment: I think that there is a way it would have to be modified by magic: in the normal wizard chess humans don't take the place of pieces. In her challenge they do.